# «Библиографический список» — плеоназм?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, значение-слов, плеоназм

Услышала от научника, что словосочетание «*библиографический список*» содержит ошибку — плеоназм. В словаре так:

**БИБЛИОГРАФИЯ**. 3. Специальный раздел журнала, содержащий краткие статьи, заметки об опубликованных изданиях, работах. Библиографический, -ая, -ое. Б. указатель. Б. отдел журнала.

Я засомневалась, потому что *библиографический список* и *библиографический указатель*, который допускает словарь в примерах, по смыслу похожи.

Насколько корректно использовать словосочетание?

Answer (score 2):

Не претендую на экспертность, но мне кажется, что разница в следующем.

**Библиография** содержит в себе список того, что использовалось при написании материала, — без привязки конкретного материала к конкретному изданию. То есть не указано, что статья на стр. 5 была написана с использованием книги Э. Автора "Научный труд", 2023.

Библиографический список имеет такое указание.

А **библиографический указатель** ещё и отсортирован по фамилиям авторов или по номеру страницы упоминания.

То есть разница в информативности. А если есть разница, то для каждого явления должно быть своё наименование, поэтому плеоназмом это не является.